# Using perl's `system`

Tags: perl, system, execution

I would like to run some command (e.g. `command`) using perl's `system()`. Suppose `command` is run from the shell like this:

```
command --arg1=arg1 --arg2=arg2 -arg3 -arg4
```

How do I use `system()` to run `command` with these arguments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Best practices: avoid the shell, use automatic error handling - [`IPC::System::Simple`](http://p3rl.org/IPC::System::Simple).

```
require IPC::System::Simple;
use autodie qw(:all);
system qw(command --arg1=arg1 --arg2=arg2 -arg3 -arg4);
```

---

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw(runx);
runx [0], qw(command --arg1=arg1 --arg2=arg2 -arg3 -arg4);
#     ↑ list of allowed EXIT_VALs, see documentation
```

Edit: a rant follows.

eugene y's answer includes a link to the documentation to system. There we can see a homungous piece of code that needs to be included everytime to do `system` properly. eugene y's answer shows but a part of it.

Whenever we are in such a situation, we bundle up the repeated code in a module. I draw parallels to proper no-frills exception handling with `Try::Tiny`, however `IPC::System::Simple` as *`system` done right* did not see this quick adoption from the community. It seems it needs to be repeated more often.

So, **use `autodie`! Use `IPC::System::Simple`!** Save yourself the tedium, be assured that you use tested code.

Comment: To do system "properly" you must decode `$?`?  I don't think so.

Comment: I'm bewildered that a man of your expertise doesn't know that indeed it needs decoding.

Comment: Well, you might simply not care about anything beyond "zero" and "not zero".

Answer (score 5):

```
my @args = qw(command --arg1=arg1 --arg2=arg2 -arg3 -arg4);
system(@args) == 0 or die "system @args failed: $?";
```

More information is in [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Answer (score 1):

As with everything in Perl, there's more than one way to do it :)

The best way, Pass the arguments as a list:

```
system("command", "--arg1=arg1","--arg2=arg2","-arg3","-arg4");
```

Though sometimes programs don't seem to play nice with that version (especially if they expect to be invoked from a shell). Perl will invoke the command from the shell if you do it as a single string.

```
system("command --arg1=arg1 --arg2=arg2 -arg3 -arg4");
```

But that form is slower.

Comment: *Speed* is not the issue with the string versus array as arguments to system: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Answer (score 1):

```
my @args = ( "command", "--arg1=arg1", "--arg2=arg2", "-arg3", "-arg4" );
system(@args);
```