# Is it possible to process exit codes > 255 with perl?

Tags: windows, perl, exit-code

First, find a little background about exit code [in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726447/why-is-the-exit-code-255-instead-of-1-in-perl/2726480#2726480) ([also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882677/why-is-the-return-value-of-perls-system-not-what-i-expect))and [on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179565/exitcodes-bigger-than-255-possible/328423#328423).

Now - when I execute another process **from a perl script** (I'm open as to the method, `qx`/`open`/`system`/`exec`/`IPC::Run`, etc.) **on Windows**:

**is it possible to capture exit codes outside the range of `0`- `255`?**

On Windows, a process can return a full (signed) 32bit exit code, and it's not so uncommon to have something return `0x8...0...`, that is, some COM error code or somesuch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aProcess) can return the full signed 32-bit exit code.  Use the `GetExitCode` method.  But it's a little tricky, because the return value is *not* the exit code (it's the return value of the Windows [GetExitCodeProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which indicates success or failure of the function).  The exit code gets stored into the variable you pass to the method.

```
use Win32::Process;
use Win32;

sub ErrorReport{
    print Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError() );
}

my $ProcessObj;
Win32::Process::Create($ProcessObj,
                       "C:\\winnt\\system32\\notepad.exe",
                       "notepad temp.txt",
                       0,
                       NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                       ".") or die ErrorReport();

$ProcessObj->Wait(INFINITE);
my $exitCode;
$ProcessObj->GetExitCode($exitCode) or die ErrorReport();
```

Comment: Excellent example. Thanks! (Now the only problem obviously is that Wait(INFINITE) is a little unresponsive :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible but it's not simple.

The [`Win32::API`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aAPI) module can expose the Windows API to Perl scripts. Use it to create a code reference for [the `GetExitCodeProcess` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28VS.85%29.aspx), invoke it with the process identifier of the dead program, and unpack the result.