# Why system doesn't return main's value?

Tags: perl, system

```
[root@ test]$ cat return10.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    return 10;
}
[root@ test]$ perl -e 'print system("/path_to_return10")'
2560
```

I was expecting **10** but got **2560**,why?

Comment: I don't think so,it never changes.

Comment: That is the return code of the system command in perl.
If you print $?, you will get the same value as 2560.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3477916#3478060

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `$?` in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

You got 10 * 256 (return value = 10) + 0 * 128 (there was no core dump) + 0 (process wasn't killed by signal).

Answer (score 6):

as specified in the documentation for the `system` call in perl (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

> The return value is the exit status of the program as returned by the
>   wait call. To get the actual exit value, shift right by eight (see
>   below).

indeed: `2560 >> 8 = 10`