# how to pass arguments from perl script to bash script

Tags: perl, grep, arguments

im trying to use grep in perl, but i have to recive arguments from perl to use them with grep options, im doing this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
system(grep -c $ARGV[0] $ARGV[1]);
```

this throws an error, how can this be implemented?

Comment: `alias grepc='grep -c $@'` in `.bashrc`

Answer (score 7):

```
system('grep', '-c', $ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]);
```

But consider whether that's what you want to do.  Perl can do a lot of things itself without invoking external programs.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477916/using-perls-system/3478060#3478060 for error handling.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) has to be a string (or list of strings).  Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
system("grep -c $ARGV[0] $ARGV[1]");
```

Comment: The list form is safer.  Consider the possibility that someone invoked your script with a first argument of `'; rm -rf $HOME'`.  That's not really an issue unless the script runs with additional privileges (the user could have run `rm -rf $HOME` directly), but it's worth thinking about.  The single-string form is useful if you need to invoke the shell to execute the command for you; for example, `system("command1 | command2")` *can* be done in Perl, but it's a lot of work.  `perldoc -f system`

Comment: It also fails for simpler stuff like `script.pl "Can't" file`

Answer (score 0):

You may not get what you expect from that code. From `perldoc -f system`:

```
The return value is the exit status of the program as returned by 
the "wait" call.
```

`system` will not actually give you the count from `grep`, just the return value from the grep process.

To be able to use the value inside perl, use `qx()` or backticks. E.g.

```
my $count  = `grep -c ... `;
# or
my $count2 = qx(grep -c ...);
```

Be aware that this will give you a newline after the number, e.g. "6\n".

However, why not use all perl?

```
my $search = shift;
my $count;
/$search/ and $count++ while (<>);
say "Count is $count";
```

The implicit `open` performed by the diamond operator `<>` can be dangerous in the wrong hands, though. You can instead open the file manually with a three-argument open:

```
use autodie;
my ($search, $file) = @ARGV;
my $count;
open my $fh, '<', $file;
/$search/ and $count++ while (<$fh>);
say "Count is $count";
```