# How to open an application via php and perl?

Tags: php, perl, apache, printing

I am trying to print generated forms / receipts through PHP (the printers will be installed on the server, I am not attempting to print to a user's local printer). I have decided to try the following methodology:

IN PHP:

1. Generate a PDF file and save it on the server.
2. Call a perl script to print said PDF file.

IN perl:

1. Use `system()` to "open" Reader and print the given PDF silently.

What works:

- I can generate PDFs in PHP.
- I can call a perl script.

  - If the script has errors, they report to the browser window. ie: If I purposely change file paths it fails, and reports the appropriate reason.
- functions such as `printf` seem to work fine as the output displays in the browser.
- The exact same perl script (with the "non-functioning" line mentioned below) works properly when executed from the command line or the IDE.

What doesn't work:

- In perl: `system('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe" /N /T "C:\\test.pdf" 0-XEROX');`

What happens:

- NOTHING! I get no errors. It just flat out refuses to open Adobe Reader. All code below this line seems to run fine. It's like the function is being ignored. I am at a loss as to why, but I did try a few things.

What I've tried:

- Changed permissions of the AcroRd32.exe to `Everyone - Full Control`.
- Output the `$?` after the `system()` call. It is `1`, but I don't know what `1` means in this case.
- Verified that there are no `disable_functions` listed in php (though I think this is unrelated as `shell_exec` seems to be working, since some of the perl code is ran).
- Various other configurations that at least got me to the point where I can confirm that PHP is in fact calling the perl script, it just isn't running the `system()` call.

Other info:

- Apache 2.2.1.7
- PHP 5.35
- Perl 5.12.3 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
- WampServer 2.1

I'm at a loss here, and while it seems like this is an Apache / permissions problem, I cannot be sure. My experience with Apache is limited, and most of what I find online is linux commands that don't work in my environment.

Comment: I can't get why you try to open Reader.

Comment: the actual command is: `system('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe" /N /T "C:\\test.pdf" 0-XEROX');`, where 0-XEROX is the name of the printer. But hey, I'm all ears as how to print the PDF another way. edit: I think that figuring out how to make the original question work is valuable in general, but my ultimate goal is to simply print the PDF, so again any help provided would be very useful.

Comment: Ah ok, now I get it. So you want to print PDFs on the fly on your printer in the moment they are created on the website. Mmm, I'm afraid I can't help. Anyway, improve the question proving the full command line you gave me. I voted up, hope you will find a solution.

Comment: I am not familiar with perl so my question is: why the double \ in the path to the software? I think, maybe the path is the one that creates the problem, have you tried creating a shortcut for `AcroRd32.exe` in a simpler path like `C:\AcroRd32.exe`

Comment: \ is an escape character, and it has to be in there for perl to recognize that I intend the actual '\' character, and not that I am escaping the next character. I appreciate the comment, but the pathing is fine. As I mentioned, this EXACT code works when I run it from the command line. This tells me that technically there are no problems with perl code itself.

Comment: Is there anything in your Apache error log?

Comment: A lot. But nothing of use here. The only thing logged today is `File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico` which of course is meaningless in my test environment.

Comment: Related: [`system` done right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3478060/46395)

Comment: @daxim I'm very new to perl, and I certainly appreciate your feedback. However, I am unsure as to how to apply it. In your answer there are 2 blocks of code. Should I be using them both? Either way, I tried the first block, and then tried both together replacing `command` and `args` with `C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 10.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe`. Yet, I get various errors, like it's trying to run `C:/Program`, and it doesn't seem to matter if I wrap it in quotes or use \ or \\ instead of /. Any advice you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: code example: `use IPC::System::Simple qw(runx); runx [0], 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 10.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe', qw(/N /T C:/test.pdf 0-XEROX);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
my @args = ('C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 10.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe');
if (system(@args) != 0) {
    # Can't run acroread.  Oh Noes!!!
    die "Unable to launch acrobat reader!\n";
}
```

The thing about system() is that it does two different things
depending on the number and type(s) of argument it gets.  If the
argument is an array or if there are multiple arguments, Perl assumes
the first is the program to run with the rest as its arguments and it
launches the program itself.

If, however it's just one string, Perl handles it differently.  It
runs your command-line interpreter (typically CMD.EXE on Windows) on
the string and lets it do what it wants with it.  This becomes
problematic pretty quickly.

Firstly, both Perl and the shell do various kinds of interpolation on
the string (e.g. replace '//' with '/', tokenize by space, etc.) and
it gets very easy to lose track of what does what.  I'm not at all
surprised that your command doesn't work--there are just so many
things that can go wrong.

Secondly, it's hard to know for sure what shell actually gets run on
Windows or what changes Perl makes to it first.  On Unix, it usually doesn't matter--every shell does more or
less the same with simple commands.  But on Windows, you could be
running raw CMD.EXE, GNU Bash or some intermediate program that
provides Unix-shell-like behaviour.  And since there are several
different ports of Perl to Windows, it could well change if you
switch.

But if you use the array form, it all stays in Perl and nothing else
happens under the hood.

By the way, the documentation for system() and $? can be found [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) and [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables).  It's well worth reading.

Comment: This helps some, guess what displays now: "Unable to launch acrobat reader!" I suppose this tells me that there is in fact an error in running the `system()` function, but it still doesn't tell me why. Is there any other output I can grab? It is executing the `die` statement, but I need to know why in order to fix it.

Comment: Apparently, `$!` gives me a bit more info: `No such file or directory`. However, it DOES exist, and works when I run the perl script from the command line... ugh.

Comment: Try putting in 'print "Found acroread!\n" if (-f $args[0]);' after the @args definition.  This will tell you if the path to acroread is correct.  If it is, try replacing the '-f' with '-x'--that will tell you if Perl has permission to run it.

Comment: I have: `print "Found acroread!\n" if (-x $args[0]);` in the line immediately after `my @args = ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe');` No matter if I use -f or -x it displays `Found acroread!` - I would like to stress again that if I run the perl script from the command line, it does in fact open Adobe Reader. Oddly, with your code it will output the `Found acroread!` and then when I close Reader it outputs the `die` statement.

Comment: I read up, and I understand what you were suggesting. So I implemented these tests, and I get a thumbs up on basically any file test: -f, -e, -w, and -r. (did not see a -x in the list of choices on the site I visited). Either way, I get the display in the console when I run it from the console, and I get the display in the browser when I run it via php. The only difference being that perl actually opens reader when ran from the console...

Comment: `-x` is documented at http://p3rl.org/-x and in `perldoc -f -x`; you should look up things in the official documentation first, not on random Web pages.