# Expanding Perl array into shell command arguments

Tags: perl

I want to invoke a shell command from a Perl script. The arguments to the command are present in a Perl array.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to call [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), and it is most efficient to pass the parameters as a list, which avoids using the shell to parse the command line. A call like

```
my $status = system 'command', @arguments;
```

should do what you need.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3478060 for a better way regarding error handling.

Answer (score 1):

There are usually two forms accepted by most functions to launch programs:

- Accepts a path and a list of arguments
- Accepts a shell command.

The first is safer, and require fewer resources.

```
system($prog, @args);             # @args > 0
system({ $prog } $prog, @args);   # @args >= 0
```

But if you must use the shell or if you must provide a shell command, there are [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aShellQuote) (if you're on a unix system) or [Win32::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aShellQuote) (if on a Win32 system) to help you.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
my $shell_cmd = shell_quote($prog, @args);
system($shell_cmd);
```

Comment: Note: You don't actually need to use an array. For both `system` and `shell_quote`, any expression that results in a list (including a list literal) is acceptable.

Comment: @daxim, oo! Didn't know about Win32::ShellQuote.