# Call another program in Perl script

Tags: c#, perl

I want to execute a program which takes in 1 text file(say like Text.exe), I want to use this output(also txt) for future use in C# program.
I'm thinking of using a Perl Script to execute that (the script does some other stuff as well), but not quite sure how to call the .exe in Perl script.
I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: For programming with best practices, read my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3478060

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
system("c:\somepath\program.exe");
```

You can add arguments to the string.

Answer (score 1):

Use back ticks:`` ` `` if you need to capture output from program.

```
my $output = `program.exe`;
```

You can find more details on different IPC methods available in Perl in [perlipc](http://p3rl.org/perlipc).

Comment: He's saying that the output is written in a txt file, so it will not capture it in this way.