# How do I make a Perl script stop when running Matlab code fails?

Tags: linux, perl, matlab

I would like to make the Perl script run some Matlab code, then wait, then run another Matlab code in Linux. If the Matlab code fails, then it should give an error message. The Perl script below would run through even when Matlab code 1 or 2 has an error. How do I make the Perl script stop and give an error message when the Matlab codes fails?

```
print("run Matlab code 1!\n");
`matlab -nodisplay -r myfile1`;

print("run Matlab code 2!\n");
`matlab -nodisplay -r myfile2`;

print("End!\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

First, store the return code of the command you are running:

```
my $returnCode = system("matlab -nodisplay -r myfile1");
```

Then, before you move to the next step, make sure the return code is 0 (or whatever indicates success in your case):

```
if ($returnCode != 0) {
    die "Command did not finish successfully.";
}
```

Just determine what is a valid return code and tell the script to die in any other case.

Comment: To enable automatic error handling with sane error messages, simply add `use autodie qw(:all)` to that program. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/3478060