# Perl chdir doesn't work

Tags: windows, perl, chdir

A previous post might be useful: [Perl system() call failed with return code 65280](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989196/perl-system-call-failed-with-return-code-65280/11995663#11995663)

Again, I've used this code many times, but it doesn't work here. I've moved all other perl instances from PATH.

Source:

```
$targetDir = "M\:\\bldforge_AOMS_DEV";
print ("targetDir=$targetDir\n");

chdir($targetDir) or die "Cant chdir to $dir $!";
$current_dir = `cd`;
print "\nCurrent dir = $current_dir\n"
```

Output:

```
Z:\>ccperl test.pl
targetDir=M:\bldforge_AOMS_DEV

Current dir =
```

Comment: Works (with `perl`) on my end - what is `ccperl`?

Comment: @zb226: see my answer to user1288329's previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11992799/6309. This is about ClearCase (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/clearcase/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure you are indeed in a ClearCase view, I would use [`cleartool pwd`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_pwd.htm):

```
$current_dir = `cleartool pwd`;
```

That will work even on Windows:

> The `cleartool pwd` command lists the current working directory.
>   This command is intended for use in interactive cleartool and multitool sessions, and in batch files or shell scripts that simulate interactive sessions.

Comment: Good idea. Anyway, it turns out as another path issue. I ran a huge .bat file to setup the environment before run the BuildForge scripts. The path somehow was not right. Once I copied the path from the current CMD window. It resolved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up `pwd` with `cd`. `cd` print only to **STDERR**, i.e. it succeeds silently.

My point is that `cd` is of no use in your case.

Comment: That is not true at all on Windows XP

Comment: `C:\>perl -e "print 'cd='.\`cd\`"` prints `cd=C:\ `

Comment: This is amazing place to ask questions! The reply is so fast and so many people online. How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

To get the current working directory, you should be using [`Cwd`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html)'s `getdcwd` function:

```
use Cwd;

my $current_dir = getdcwd 'M:';
```