# Not able to install ClearCase::CtCmd module

Tags: perl, clearcase

I'm getting below error while installing ClearCase::CtCmd.  I'm getting this error even after installing MinGW.

```
c:\temp\CtCmd-1.08>perl Makefile.PL
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Looking for Version     12      Not Found
Cannot find  C:\Perl\site\bin\gcc.exe -> Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 12 at Makefile.PL line 162.
```

My perl version is

```
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 16 subversion 2) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=MSWin32, osvers=5.2, archname=MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
    uname=''
    config_args='undef'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=undef
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=undef, use64bitall=undef, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='C:\Perl\site\bin\gcc.exe', ccflags ='-DNDEBUG -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE -DNO_STRICT -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPL
ICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T -DHASATTRIBUTE -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields',
    optimize='-O2',
    cppflags='-DWIN32'
    ccversion='', gccversion='3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=1234
    d_longlong=undef, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=8
    ivtype='long', ivsize=4, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='__int64', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
```

Answer (score 1):

The [CtCmd the Perl extension for ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21119963) should run, according to its [dependency page](http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=ClearCase::CtCmd;perl=latest), with a Perl 5.16.2 (which you have).

I would not use a perl on MinGW for that, but a [Perl directly for Windows](http://www.perl.org/get.html#win32).
If it is not working, check out the Perl included with Rational ClearCase itself ([`ccperl` or `ratperl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11992799/6309)).

Comment: I had active perl in my system, when i tried to install CtCmd module it prompted me to install MinGW. After installing MinGW i got stuck with gcc version problem.

Comment: The gcc compiler is supposed to be automatically downloaded by ActivePerl if needed (I have heard--haven't used it myself).  It is also provided with Strawberry Perl by default, which is what I use.

Comment: @maestromani you can install it with http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RA/RATL/ (simple archive). The path to Microsoft Visual Studio and to Perl must be in the PATH.

Comment: @VonC,@dan1111, I did the following now.

Comment: @VonC,@dan1111, I did the following now. 1. Installed latest active perl in my machine, 2. tried to install Clearcase::Ctcmd and got following error `c:\temp\CtCmd-1.08>perl Makefile.PL

It looks like you don't have a C compiler on your PATH, so you will not be
able to compile C or XS extension modules.  You can install GCC from the
MinGW package using the Perl Package Manager by running:

    ppm install MinGW

Looking for Version     12      Not Found
Cannot find  cl -> Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 12 at Makefile.PL line 162.` 3. tried installing MinGw using  ppm

Comment: Below is log while installing MinGW, `c:\temp\CtCmd-1.08>ppm install MinGW
Downloading ActiveState Package Repository packlist...done
Updating ActiveState Package Repository database...done
Syncing site PPM database with .packlists...done
Downloading MinGW-5.1.4.1...done
Downloading dmake-4.11.20080107...done
Unpacking MinGW-5.1.4.1...done
Unpacking dmake-4.11.20080107...done
Generating HTML for MinGW-5.1.4.1...done
Generating HTML for dmake-4.11.20080107...done
Updating files in site area...done
1070 files installed
` Ran into same error posted while installing Ctcmd.

Comment: @maestromani did you try the same installation, but with `ccperl` or `ratperl` (ie the perl already included in a ClearCase installation), and Visual Studio compiler in the PATH?

Comment: @vonc, same error with ccperl. Error --> C:\temp\CtCmd-1.08>ccperl Makefile.PL
Looking for Version     12      Not Found
Cannot find  cl -> Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 12 at Makefile.PL line 162.,