# Perl: Calling a perl script from another

Tags: perl

I have a perl script which calls another script. I am calling it using backticks and passing argument to that script and it works fine.

```
`CQPerl call_script.pl $agr1 $agr2 $arg3`;
```

But please suggest if there is another better way to do so. How can I check if the script errored out because of the calling script or the script that was called. How do I do that check from the calling script itself?

Comment: Backticks capture the standard output of the other script; you're then not doing anything very much with it (like assigning it to something).  Are you sure you need backticks?

Comment: Use `autodie`! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477916/using-perls-system

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you wan't to do error checking, backticks may be a wrong approach. You probably want to use the `system` function. See the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for all the details of error handling, examples included.

Perl has a number of possibilites to execute other scripts / commands:

- **backticks / `qx{}`** When you want to read all the output at once after the program has terminated
- **`exec`** When you wan't to continue your process as another program — never returns if succesfull
- **`system`** When you are only interested in the success or failure of the command
- **`open`** When you want to pipe information to or from the command
- **`do` and `require`** Execute another Perl script here. Similar to C's `#include`
- There are modules to do a three-way `open` so that you have access to `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` of the program you executed. See the apropriate parts of [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) for advanced information.

And always use the multi-argument forms of these calls to avoid shell escaping (can be annoying and very insecure).

Comment: Thanks, I guess 
if(system("CQPerl call_script.pl $arg1 $arg2 $agr3")) {
    print "ERROR: in calling script";
} 
will answer my question

Comment: maybe useful additional info: return of **backticks /** `qx` [can be used to catch STDOUT lines in scalar or array context](https://perlmaven.com/qx); return of `system` contains the [exit code](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-exit-from-perl-script) or the [signal the process died from](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$?). Regarding `do`: [In perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do) there is an example how to implement error handling (however, I could not manage to `do` another perl script which uses `exit`, since the calling script always stopped).

Comment: Is the STDOUT / STDERR of a `system` call really lost in nirvana or is there a chance to catch it in the perl script?

Comment: @MattTT Child processes inherit file descriptors like STDOUT from the parent processes. The output doesn't get lost, it usually just bypasses the parent process and is written directly e.g. to a file or a terminal. Of course, you can reopen STDOUT in the parent process so that this file descriptor is now a pipe that you can (concurrently) read in the parent process. But system() wouldn't work here, because this function blocks until the child is done. Instead you'd have to use fork() + exec(). At that point, you're reinventing IPC::Run

Answer (score 5):

Check the value of the perl special variable `$?` to determine if there was an error.

Comment: Nice feature, I did not know about $? Thanks!